# how to implement mapbox.js offline caching

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mapbox

I'm creating a **phonegap** mobile app that have a map in it.
I'm using [mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/)

i know that it allows offline capability but i couldn't figure out how to do it
i searched on how to but i could not find the documentation

this is my code so far

```
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'accessToken';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'id')
        .setView([-37.82, 175.215], 14);

    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
        var a = addressPoints[i];
        var title = a[2];
        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'post', 'marker-color': '0044FF'}),
            title: title
        });
        marker.bindPopup(title);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }

    map.addLayer(markers);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know who told you or where you read that it's possible while using mapbox-js (some kind of reference would be nice) but it isn't and that's why you can't find it. However, it is possible using the iOS or Android SDK's:

https://www.mapbox.com/help/ios-offline/

https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-offline/